# How to assign a new colum which value starts from 1 to N based on time sequence and duplicated values in dataframe?

Tags: pandas

Example:

```
id      date      seq 
a    2019/11/01    1
a    2019/12/01    2
b    2019/10/01    1
c    2019/12/01    2
c    2019/11/01    1
```

I want to assign column `seq` base on columns `date and id` , the latter is duplicated. The details as belows:

- For values which are not duplicate in column `id` like `b`, it will get 1 in column `seq`.
- For values which are duplicated in column `id` like `a` and `c`, it will start 1 from N(N is repeated frequency) based on time sequence (column `date`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with converting values to datetimes and sorting before:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(['id','date'])

df['seq'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount() + 1
print (df)
  id       date  seq
0  a 2019-11-01    1
1  a 2019-12-01    2
2  b 2019-10-01    1
4  c 2019-11-01    1
3  c 2019-12-01    2
```

If need same order like in original add [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.sort_index()
print (df)
  id       date  seq
0  a 2019-11-01    1
1  a 2019-12-01    2
2  b 2019-10-01    1
3  c 2019-12-01    2
4  c 2019-11-01    1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html) method

```
import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,3,3],
                       'date':['2019/11/01',
    '2019/12/01',
    '2019/10/01',
    '2019/12/01',
    '2019/11/01']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])  # first convert to datetime
df['seq'] = df.groupby('id')['date'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)


   id       date  seq
0   1 2019-11-01    1
1   1 2019-12-01    2
2   2 2019-10-01    1
3   3 2019-12-01    2
4   3 2019-11-01    1
```